# WDS server without DHCP server (DHCP from Cisco switch 375)

Tags: dhcp, switch, wds

i want to create a WDS(windows server 2012) server in my environment

my environment divided in multiple subnets DHCP provided from a Cisco switch 375 not from a windows server

is it possible to configure WDS in such an environment???

WDS server IP 192.168.1.XX

most of workstation are in 192.168.29.XX, 30.XX, 31.XX, 32.XX, 33.XX networks

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answer found on technet:

```
Predefined Option 43 - 010400000000FF
Custom-made Option 60 - String - PXEClient
Predefined Option 66 - IP or Hostname of the WDS Server (in our case 10.150.150.1)
Predefined Option 67 - boot\x86\wdsnbp.com
I did some more research and actually did a deployment following these steps in a production environment.

One more thing to keep an eye on are open ports that need to be open to the WDS server:
UDP - 67, 68, 69, 4011
TCP - 135, 137, 138, 139, 5040
```

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e84c8a4c-a6da-4c4a-8ca6-2a1007b205ae/wds-server-and-dhcp-server-on-two-different-servers?forum=winserversetup